# Selectively ignore thrown exceptions in C# code

Tags: c#, debugging

I have a function in C# code where a NullReferenceException is thrown periodically (expected behavior), but caught. Is there a way I can tell the Visual Studio debugger to not break on this exception for this particular section of my code?

*EDIT* I need to break on this exception elsewhere in my code, but not in the same function.

Comment: A good way to do it is to not allow it to happen. Why are you not able to prevent it?

Comment: It could be external code outside of his control

Comment: It's not that I'm not able to, it's code I inherited and I'm trying not to touch too much of it until I fix some of the bugs that are plaguing it. Basically I have some quick fixes I need to get out to clients before I go and rewrite anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand correctly and what you're trying to do is debug some NullReferenceException(s) but want to temporarily ignore others while debugging, you might be able to do this by marking functions that you want the debugger to ignore with the [DebuggerNonUserCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggernonusercodeattribute.aspx) attribute.

```
[DebuggerNonUserCode]
private void MyMethod()
{
    // NullReferenceException exceptions caught in this method will
    //  not cause the Debugger to stop here..
}
```

**NOTE** that this will only work if the exceptions are caught in said methods. It's just that they won't cause the debugger to break if you have the debugger set to always break on `NullReferenceException` exceptions. And that this only works on methods, and not arbitrary sections of code inside of a method..

Comment: This is actually perfect for what I need to do. It's not a permanent change, more or less just something to help me debug for now.

Comment: Doesn't work. -- At least not in VS 2015. -- I decorated a method with this, the exception is caught and does not bubble up, but the debugger STILL stops there.

Comment: Make sure to enable the "Just My Code" option in VS > Tools > Options > Debugging > General. The annotation won't be honored if this setting is not enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the exception does not bubble up to the caller, this can be achieved with [DebuggerHiddenAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerhiddenattribute.aspx).

From the remarks

> the Visual Studio 2005 debugger does not stop in a method marked with
>   this attribute and does not allow a breakpoint to be set in the
>   method.

```
    [DebuggerHidden]
    private static void M()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //log or do something useful so as not to swallow.
        }            
    }
```

Comment: For what I am attempting to do, what is the difference between specifying the [DebuggerNonUserCode] attribute and the [DebuggerHidden] attribute?

Comment: @BasedAsFunk - Clarity.  If you are hiding code because its, say, generated and should not be looked at by the end user then DebuggerNonUserCode identifies this intention.  However, if you want to have a function that is ignored by the debugger, then DebuggerHidden identifies that intention.

Comment: Doesn't work.  The debugger just stops one level up.  The exception is NOT bubbling up, it's being caught, but the debugger behaves as though it did.  (And when you step, you can clearly see that it's not bubbling up, but the break still happens. -- VERY ANNOYING.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it does effect all exceptions in the solution.

`Debug -> Exceptions -> Find... "Null Ref"`, de-tick Thrown.

Comment: Again, he still needs it to break on that exception for the rest of his code, there's just one place where he wants to ignore it.