# Disable Console output of all Handled/Caught Exceptions in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

I'm currently using a library that throws (and handles) about 5 exceptions when a request to get something fails. Normally this isn't a problem since it's expected this might happen, but the problem is that Visual Studio will log these exceptions anyway.

Is there a way to disable Visual Studio from outputting caught exceptions to the debug console? I still want all other exceptions that would cause a break to be logged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ask Visual Studio to care about the exceptions in your code only, using the [Just My Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx) option.

Go to the "Debug" menu and click on "Options and Settings", and then Enable Just My Code:

[image: Just My Code]

This has been [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40151182/can-i-get-visual-studio-to-ignore-a-specific-instance-of-an-exception) on StackOverflow too.

Then, if the methods that are throwing the exception belong to a project that is... your code, you can decorate them with the `DebuggerNonUserCode` attribute:

[image: DebuggerNonUserCode]

which combined with the "Just My Code" option will produce the desired behaviour.
More on the topic [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/02/12/using-the-debuggernonusercode-attribute-in-visual-studio-2015/).

Comment: Currently the library throwing the error is compiled by me due to the NuGet version lacking the latest fixes. Is there a way to disable them for specific projects?

EDIT: Looks like just putting them in Release mode solves that problem. Just My Code was already enabled. Thanks!

Comment: I added a possible solution to my answer, to take that into account.

Comment: I read that `DebuggerNonUserCode` works only after executing the following command: `reg add HKCUSoftwareMicrosoftVisualStudio14.0_ConfigDebuggerEngine /v AlwaysEnableExceptionCallbacksOutsideMyCode /t REG_DWORD /d 1` This registry key will only work in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and beyond. Source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/using-the-debuggernonusercode-attribute-in-visual-studio-2015/