# Debugger.Break() when already at breakpoint

Tags: c#, debugging, mono, xamarin-studio

I like to call Debugger.Break() on various error conditions. I find this is a more effective way to debug than is throwing an exception.

The problem happens when I am already broken in the debugger. If that's the case, the debugger understandably gives up and dies. I would greatly prefer to simply not break in that case.

Is there a way to determine whether the debugger is already breaking? Or, failing that, a way to tell the debugger to just ignore a break call if it is already breaking?

Comment: _"I find this is a more effective way to debug than is throwing an exception."_ Doesn't the debugger pause when an unhandled exception is thrown? In any case, a debugger is usually either running or not; you're going to need to clarify what you mean by a "breaking" debugger.

Comment: Scattering Debugger.Break calls around code seems like a poor way to debug. The only use I've had for Debugger is Debugger.Assert to easily attach a debugger initially to a command-line application running outside VS. When already debugging, use breakpoints / stepping / breaking on first-chance exceptions.. there is no need to throw an exception simply to debug.

Comment: I don't scatter the calls; there is exactly one Debugger.Break call in the app, which in turn is triggered by other code. The problem with breaking on exceptions is that if I break on every exception, then TaskCancelledException gets really annoying. If I break only on unhandled exceptions, then the call stack unwinds. Additionally, sometimes code that is not mine throws exceptions, and I don't want to break.

Comment: @WilliamJockusch that doesn't work as an excuse for me - you should always throw an exception if you have an exceptional situation, period. If you're getting a lot of exceptions then you're probably doing something else wrong.

Comment: OK, fine, I'm doing it wrong, whatever. It works for me. Is there an answer to my question?

Comment: @WilliamJockusch Not that I know of because it doesn't make much sense - You can't pause something that is already paused. Just throw exceptions and if you really need to then [filter out the ones you don't want](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275139/selectively-ignore-thrown-exceptions-in-c-sharp-code)

Comment: @WilliamJockusch It is possible to exclude certain exceptions (ie. TaskCanceledException) from being debugger breakpoints - see the Debug > Exceptions window. Small utility methods that "often throw a common exception that doesn't matter" can be marked with DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute. Using Debugger.Break when triggered by anything but a command-line flag or option (ie. provide an early attach point) may indicate coding into the problem..

Comment: Yes, I know . . . but . . . Xamarin . . . don't get me wrong, I love them . . . but they WILL screw something up in most releases; frequently this involves exceptions. Xamarin Studio (or VS Mac) is not Visual studio . . . but above all, exceptions that are not mine, I don't want to be bothered by them. So my default is to call my BreakPoint method on all exceptional conditions, and maybe throw an exception in addition; I even have a BreakingException for just that purpose. It works for me. I think I can even work out a way to detect if I'm at a breakpoint with pretty high accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do it. I imagine one could get it to fail if one tried hard enough.

```
public static bool AtBreakPoint() {
  Task<int> task = Task.Run(() => 2);
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    if (task.IsCompleted) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```